# перегрузка операторов для массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, перегрузка-операторов

Поставлена задача : для класса массив применить перегрузку оператора `&` , которая бы выполняла сдвиг матрицы по столбцам на К столбцов. 
типа инструкция `М1 = К & М`; 
Сформировал процедуру сдвига `Sdvig_K()`, и переопределил оператор присваивания `М1 = М`;
А вот сочинить  перегрузку для операции `&` не получается. Подскажите, "куда копать", "как копать"?

Comment: спасибо. буду пробовать.

Comment: А чем заполняются освободившиеся колонки при сдвиге? Или это циклический сдвиг?

Comment: да - циклический. вполне работает.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, раз уж у вас `Sdvig_K()`, как я понимаю, член класса, как

```
Massiv Massiv::operator & (int K)
{ 
    Massiv result(*this);
    result.Sdvig_K(K);
    return result;
}
```

Если надо, чтоб первым шел именно `K`- то только как свободная функция:

```
Massiv operator & (int K, const Massiv& M)
{ 
    Massiv result(M);
    result.Sdvig_K(K);
    return result;
}
```

Примерно так...

Comment: спасибо . буду пробовать.

Comment: в области описания переопределения даёт сообщение об ошибке " слишком много параметров для этой функции оператора".

Comment: А в строке вызова оператора сообщает "выражение должно относится к целочисленному типу"...

Comment: Дайте полный текст, без этого понять, что и как у вас там трудно, телепатия сегодня на дальние расстояния не работает. Выложите где-нибудь типа на http://vpaste.net/

Comment: Я впервые работаю с такими сервисами. может что не так

Comment: http://vpaste.net/4R75H

Comment: извиняюсь за "оперативность" - и связь не очень и время (по местным меркам)  позднее - засыпаю...

Comment: У вас в `void K_sdvig(int n, int m, int K);` 3 параметра. А должен быть только один - `K`. Как вы себе представляете запись оператора `&` с четырьмя параметрами? Он бинарный...

Comment: @Николай вместо "спасибо" в комментариях проголосуйте за ответ (стрелки слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Так как вы не показали, как вы определили класс матрицы, то я импровизировал. Тем не менее вы можете посмотреть, как определить требуемые операторы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

template <size_t N>
class Matrix
{
private:
    int a[N][N];
public:
    Matrix() : a{}
    {
        //
    }

    Matrix<N> & operator =( const Matrix<N> &m )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
        {
            std::copy( std::begin( m.a[i] ), 
                       std::end( m.a[i] ), 
                       std::begin( a[i] ) );
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix<N> & randomly_init()
    {
        std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

        for ( auto &row : a )
        {
            for ( int &x : row ) x = std::rand() % N;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Matrix<N> & rotate( size_t n )
    {
        if ( ( n %= N ) != 0  )
        {
            for ( auto &row : a )
            {
                std::rotate( std::begin( row ), 
                             std::next( std::begin( row ), N - n ), 
                             std::end( row ) );
            }                    
        }

        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Matrix<N> &m )
    {
        size_t n = N;
        size_t w = 0;

        do { ++w; } while ( n /= 10 );

        for ( auto &row : m.a )
        {
            for ( auto x : row ) os << std::setw( w ) << x << ' ';
            os << std::endl;
        }

        return os;
    }

    friend Matrix<N> operator &( size_t n, const Matrix<N> &m  )
    {
        return Matrix<N>( m ).rotate( n );
    }

    friend Matrix<N> operator &( const Matrix<N> &m, size_t n  )
    {
        return Matrix<N>( m ).rotate( n );
    }
};

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    Matrix<N> m;

    m.randomly_init();

    std::cout << m << std::endl;

    m.rotate( 1 );

    std::cout << m << std::endl;

    m = ( N - 1 ) & m;  

    std::cout << m << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
0 1 0 3 0 
3 4 2 3 0 
3 0 1 0 4 
2 4 2 0 3 
0 3 4 0 2 

0 0 1 0 3 
0 3 4 2 3 
4 3 0 1 0 
3 2 4 2 0 
2 0 3 4 0 

3 0 0 1 0 
3 0 3 4 2 
0 4 3 0 1 
0 3 2 4 2 
0 2 0 3 4
```

В принципе для этого определения класса можно было не определять явно копирующий оператор присваивания. Создаваемый компилятором по умолчанию оператор присваивания вполне подходит. Однако если у вас класс определен так, что вы в нем динамически выделяете память, то вам надо будет явно определить по крайней мере конструктор копирования, копирующий оператор присваивания и деструктор.

Comment: Спасибо за ёмкий  ответ. буду изучать... когда просплюсь ...

Comment: мои каракули тут http://vpaste.net/4R75H

Comment: @Николай Ваш код неверный. По крайней мере в функции сдвига, вы не удаляете целиком память, выделенную под вспомогательный массив.

Comment: спасибо. буду копать и тут то же

Comment: @Николай Используйте мой класс. Просто объявите массив внутри класса как имеющий элементы типа float, если вам так надо.:)

Comment: @Николай вместо "спасибо" в комментариях проголосуйте за ответ (стрелки слева от ответа).

Comment: Ваш код интересен, но не для моего случая. Я конечно не уточнял в задаче, но требуется иметь класс динамического массива, его размер задаётся в процессе работы программы. У меня не получается перестроить ваш код. И почему то MS VS-2015  на инструкцию std::copy -жутко ругается... даже ваш код внятно не проходит...

Comment: @Николай  Мой код должен уомпилироваться без проблем. Видимо, вы запускаете не мой код, а свой код, добавив в мой код директиву using namespace std.:)